# Operator precedence in programming language

Tags: programming-languages, context-free-grammar

In programming Language class, I learned operator precedence and associativity.  The under is simple *Context-Free-Grammar*

```
<expr> -> <expr> + <term> | <term>
<term> -> <term> * <fact> | <fact>
<fact> -> (<expr>) | a
```

By using Context-Free-Grammar above, we can make the sentence

```
a+a+(a+a)
```

I think, the order of operation should be done as follow : (a+a) -> a+a then plus altogether. However, on lecture, the professor said both (a+a) -> a+a and 
a+a -> (a+a) order is right. Student's are in panic. Even in the sentence below,

```
(a+a)+((a+a))
```

Both order ((a+a)) -> (a+a) then plus and (a+a) -> ((a+a)) is correct.
He just said, after making parse tree, then converted to the assembly language
so the order depends on Compiler.

I don't understand his explanation.
Is anybody can explain why there are two possible order??

Comment: Note that the grammar as given is ambiguous. `<term> + <fact>` should probably be `<term> * <fact>`.

Comment: @MichaelDyck correct. My typo

Comment: @MichaelDyck, a quick question, If I want to add '&' operator at the lowest precedence than all other operators in the above grammar then how can I approach this scenario. I know stack overflow is not a discussion site, but I am really struggling with this. In the same grammar I want to add '&'.

Comment: @PrasannaSasne: I won't answer that here, because it's not really relevant to the question above. You could ask it as its own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluation order is independent of grouping. If you need to calculate `X + Y` (where `X` and `Y` are sub expressions), it does not matter whether you first compute `temp2 = Y` and then `temp1 = X` or the other way around. At the end `temp1 + temp2` has the same value.

Sometimes it is more convenient to compute the right-hand argument first. (Maybe you already know it from a previous computation, for example.)

If the computation of `X` or `Y` has a side effect, that might need to be taken into account. Some languages insist that side effects happen left to right; others allow any order. But in no case does parenthesis grouping affect the *order* of computation. It only determines what is computed.